# How to set ArrayAdapter<String> from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

How can I set `id.setAdapter(adapter);` from `SharedPreferences`? I would like that when app close all `id.getText().toString()` should be present

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private SharedPreferences atPrefs;
atPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
id = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.id);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
id.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
id.setThreshold(1);

submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (id.getText().toString().length() >= 3) {
            
            atPrefs.edit().putString(pos, id.getText().toString()).commit();
            adapter.add(atPrefs.getString(pos, ""));
            
            Intent nextscreen = new Intent(Login.this, Otp.class);
            startActivity(nextscreen);
            // finish();
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### Solved

solved with following code

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {

    list.add(0, (String) prfs.getString(String.valueOf(i), "null"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (id.getText().toString().length() >= 3) {
    
        list.add(0, (String) id.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        
        edit.putString(String.valueOf(i), id.getText().toString());
        edit.putInt("counter", i + 1);
        edit.apply();
        
        id.setText("");
        
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: in this if i close app data is going

Comment: why are you using sharedpreference ?. use database instead.

Comment: it just small say only 2-3 entries

Comment: Print the string AND the key - you are probably retrieving with wrong key. Do not use a db for this, of course

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android), keeping values in SharedPreferences is not such a good idea.

Also you are not using shared preferences correctly, you only save the value in and never get it back using _context.getString.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putStringArray("myarray", list);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  list = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("myarry");

}
```

Comment: Essentially it would be the same argument as using global variables, it should be avoided. The data you are storing is Activity specific, not application specific so every time you get a reference to Shared Preferences you load in memory all the values saved in it. When you will have more activities, you will end up loading unnecessary values of other activities that are in the background, not to mention that everyone other activity is allowed to make changes to the values you saved.

Comment: den i used putStringArrayList but still i am not getting data when i close app and open it again

Comment: I disagree - SP are ideal for this - and keeping the keys private should help you minimize the activity interaction